# how useEffect maintain the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My questions is conceptual and that is we all know that using useEffect Hook, every time when useEffect calls after every render React cleans up use Effects from the previous render before running the effects next time and declares useEffect again with his new render. **How useEffect maintains the previous state?**.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your question but if I did correctly: it looks like you're trying to use useEffect to synchronize some state to the props you're given. I think this is a bad pattern and you should not use state in the children component: just compute the value and if it's an expensive one then you can add a useMemo

Comment: Why it should maintain the previous state? It just runs the function depending on some condition, you have closures to "save" the state in the function logic.

Comment: no i am not doing that and for that i know that use useLayoutEffect is used for sync but my question is different. my question if "react cleans up use Effects from the previous render before running the effects next time and declares useEffect again" then how React maintains the previous state. for example i give value count is 0 and after update count become 1 and then and after render useEffect is cleaned and declared again then how an why we are getting count value of 1.

Comment: Please edit the question with an example you trying to figure out.

Comment: useEffect doesn't have anything to do with state that's why

Answer (score -1):

Just [google it](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/03/11/deep-dive-how-do-react-hooks-really-work/). In short, react knows which components are mounting, mounted, etc. It keeps track of them all. Because it keeps track of them all, it can assign arbitrary data to each one. This is essentially what hooks are.

All hooks do is essentially provide a mechanism to allow instance variables (some form of internal state, but not "state" like you think in react) for functional components.